# Trigger input after mousedown

Tags: javascript, triggers, click, focus, mousedown

I want to focus at the input when click at a class this did not work, does anyone have a solution.

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.pac-item',function(e){
    $("#search").trigger( "focus" );
    console.log("mousedown");
});

<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="...">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) function:

```
$("#search").focus();
```

Comment: somehow this does not work, but I still get the console output